# HLS - Acceptable segment duration margin of error

Tags: javascript, node.js, http-live-streaming

When processing media playlists I am occasionally running into a floating point precision issue with javascript where the #EXTINF is 6.0, but the duration, when multiplied by 1000 (to get ms) returns 6001. Is there a "standard" acceptable margin of error for segment durations? We were just going to go with 1/10 of the chunklist's target duration as a quick google search didn't reveal any immediate/obvious answers.

Answer (score 0):

It really only matters for seeking, so as long as the errors don’t accumulate over time. Small errors will make no difference.